# Configuring multiple monitors (with xinerama?)

Tags: 10.10, multiple-monitors, enlightenment

I am trying to get multiple monitors (I believe Xinerama is the current solution?) set up and working with Enlightenment.

However, I noticed that (1) it's hard to find current information and (2), my xorg.conf file disappeared, (now it's xorg.conf.d/?), and I don't seem to have an xorg.conf.d/ file for my monitor.

Multiple monitors works fine with the Gnome default environment, but if I recall correctly, I just ticked a box to make that happen.

What do I use to configure multiple monitors?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!